# Extract data-set with a given range from a larger dataset

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dataframe, sorting

I have a 2D data-set of type with (X,Y) values as such:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 99.96 | 2 |
| 99.76 | 4 |
| 100.15 | 6 |
| 100.28 | `0 |
| 100.66 | 11 |
| 101.17 | 14 |
| 102.36 | 4 |

I wish to extract a part of above 2D data-set such that 100.00 <= X <= 100.99 and its corresponding Y-values.
So the output generated would be as such:

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 100.15 | 6 |
| 100.28 | `0 |
| 100.66 | 11 |

Can anybody please let me know how do we go about doing this in Python?

Comment: Hi, @RanjanPal - does the post help you?  Or any follow-up questions?

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielHao for your suggestions. However, is there any similar logic that can be applied for numpy.ndarray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a data frame from your data using pandas and filter using between.

you can use pd.read_csv , pd.read_excel, pd.from_dict, etc to easily transform your source data.

```py
import pandas as pd

# example pd read csv
# df = pd.read_csv('somefile.csv', header=0)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[2,3],[4,5]], columns=['a','b'])

print(df[df['a'].between(2,4)])


#   a  b
#1  3  4
#3  2  3
#4  4  5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @KJDII for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just a simple loop, without any `3rd party` package?
If you need to save the result, then you just substitute the `print` statement with  `result.append()`.

```py
data = [[99.96, 2],
        [97, 4],
        [100.15,6],
        [100.28,0],
        [101.17, 14],
        [102.36, 11]]


for x, y in data:
    #print(x, y)
    
    if 100.00 <= x <= 100.99:
        print(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielHao for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If the given data is of type "numpy.ndarray" then we can use of 'where' command as such:

```
import numpy as np

# Origianl data
data =  np.array([[99.96,2],[99.76,4],[100.15,6],[100.28,0],[100.66,11],[101.17,14],[102.36,4]])
print("\n","Original data=\n",data)


# Extracted Data
data_extracted = data[np.where((data[:,0] >= 100.001) & ( data[:,0]<= 100.999))]
print("\n","Extracted data=\n",data_extracted)
```